# Which feature detection algorithm does cv2.Stitcher() use?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, feature-extraction, feature-detection, image-stitching

I just learnt about SIFT, ORB & SURF algorithms and how they are used for feature detection & extraction, and Homography & RANSAC techniques used in Image Fusion. While SIFT & SURF algorithms are patented and mostly have better accuracy ([source1](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1710/1710.02726.pdf#:%7E:text=We%20showed%20that%20ORB%20is,SIFT%20show%20almost%20similar%20performances.), [source2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226554/the-pro-and-con-of-brief-and-orb-compared-to-sift)), ORB algorithm is lightweight and Open Sourced.

OpenCV Stitcher function ([documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/d8d/classcv_1_1Stitcher.html)) is built such that it can be used even without knowing the entire image stitching pipeline.

So I am curious to know, which algorithms are used (especially for feature detection & extraction) in the cv2.Stitcher class? Also is it possible to choose different algorithms other than the default ones, used in its implementation?

Comment: Sift is no longer patented :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stitcher class uses ORB by Default:

```
stitcher->setFeaturesFinder(ORB::create());
```

in [stitcher.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/stitching/src/stitcher.cpp)

You can use [stitching_detailed.py](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/samples/python/stitching_detailed.py)/[stitching_detailed.cpp](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/dd8/samples_2cpp_2stitching_detailed_8cpp-example.html) or the [stitching](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching) python package to play around with different detectors